# g++ - Virtual methods creates symbols in generated binary I can't hide

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, virtual, symbols

I am compiling a library and I need to hide the most information possible 
in the binary (not to reveal methods used). I am using tools like **strip** 
to do so, but when running the **strings** tools on the generated library,
I keep finding symbols containing the name of some of my classes in it. 
The concerned classes are the one using virtual methods.

Let's illustrate the problem.

I want to compile the following program and hide the class **A** and 
**B** in the binary:

```
namespace test {

class A {
 public:
  virtual void foo() {};
};

class B: public A { 
};

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  test::B b;
  b.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it with g++:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
$ g++ main.cpp
```

If I look for all symbols related with **test** namespace I have the following result:

```
$strings a.out | grep test
N4test1BE
N4test1AE
_ZN4test1AC2Ev
_ZN4test1A3fooEv
_ZTVN4test1BE
_ZN4test1BC1Ev
_ZTIN4test1BE
_ZTVN4test1AE
_ZTSN4test1AE
_ZTIN4test1AE
_ZN4test1AC1Ev
_ZTSN4test1BE
_ZN4test1BC2Ev
```

I understand that the symbols starting with **_Z** are related to the 
different class methods (even if I am not sure about the difference between
**_ZN**, **_ZTV**, **_ZTI** and **_ZTS**). But I don't get what are the two 
symbols **N4test1BE** and **N4test1AE**.

If I strip all the symbols:

```
$ strip --strip-all --discard-all a.out 
$ strings a.out | grep test
N4test1BE
N4test1AE
```

I can't remove thoses two symbols.

Can someone help me to understand what they are and how to remove them from the binary?

My intuition is that it is related with the **VTable** but I don't really know how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Why is this so important? Somebody can always reverse engineer the stuff? Are you just being paranoid?

Comment: It uses a lot of mathematics algorithms from research. It is difficult to understand why it works knowing the implementation, but easier if you know what mathematics tools are used.

Furthermore I want to know what are thoses because I am curious :) (an easy way is to rename everything but I would not have learnt anything from that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These strings are coming from the run-time type information (RTTI). Specifically, they're what enables `typeid(obj).name()` to return an identifying name.

If you don't need this, you can turn it off with `-fno-rtti`. Beware that some standard C++ features require RTTI. When disabling it, what you get is not quite C++, and you may need to adjust some of your code to keep it working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. It looks like you are right,  I will do more research to understand what RTTI is, but your solution works !